# How can I set unit in a cloudwatch math expression?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

I have a clouwatch math metric `e1` that is `SUM([m1,m2])`. `m1` and `m2` have CloudWatch Unit of `Milliseconds` but the `SUM` expression has unit `No unit`.

[image]

Is there any way to assign a units to math expressions in CloudWatch? I want to show `e1`,`m1`,`m2` in the same chart and it says `Various units` in the Y-label axis instead of saying `Milliseconds`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only workaround that I know is to go to the chart Options and set `Left Y axis Label` to `Milliseconds` and unchecking `Show units`. This does not actually give the match expression a unit but it shows ok in the chart.